# If component functions are injective then is the function injective?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

If we have injective continuously differentiable function $f$, and if we define continuously differentiable function $g(x,y)=(f(x),y)$, then does it follow that $g$ is injective?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to answer this yourself?  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Well I'm proving that $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not injective by assuming it is injective.  I've parameterized a function  $g:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$, and am going to use the inverse function theorem to finish the proof.  I have a theorem that gives me conditions when for $g$ when it's $C^r$, $detf'(x,y)\neq 0$ and injective.  I've gotten my parameterized function $g$ to meet the first 2 conditions, but since the first component function is $f(x,y)$ and the second is $y$, both injective, I need this to imply that $g$ is injective, so I can apply my theorem

Comment: You don't need continuity, much less differentiability.  What does it mean for the function to be injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for $g$ to be injective means that $g(x_0,y_0) = g(x_1,y_1)$ implies that $(x_0,y_0) = (x_1,y_1)$.  Start by assuming the antecedent and try to prove the consequent.  (Note that you don't need to use the fact that either $f$ or $g$ is continuously differentiable.)

Comment: $g(x,y)=g(x_1,y_1)$ $\Longrightarrow \bigg(f(x,y),y\bigg) = \bigg(f(x_1,y_1),y_1\bigg)$ $\Longrightarrow   \bigg(f(x,y),y\bigg) -\bigg(f(x_1,y_1),y_1\bigg)=0$ $\Longrightarrow $ and then by subtracting vectors we can conclude that each component is equal to $0$

Comment: Well, you get that $f(x,y)=f(x_1,y_1)$ and $y=y_1$.  From here you still need to show that $x=x_1$.  How can you do that?

Comment: We are given that $f$ is injective, so because we have $y=y_1 \Longrightarrow f(x,y)=f(x_1,y)$, it follows that $x=x_1$.  But since we are given that $f(x,y) $ is injective, couldn't we just conclude from $f(x,y)=f(x_1,y_1)$ that $x=x_1$ and $y=y_1$ without having to know prior that $y=y_1$?

Comment: Yes, it is just superfluous information.  More generally, note that this same line of thinking implies that, for any $g(x,y) = (f(x,y),h(x,y))$, where $h$ is injective or not, the fact that $f$ is injective forces $g$ to be injective as well.

Comment: So if we had $g(x,y) = \big(f(x,y),h(x,y)\big)$ and got to $f(x,y)=f(x_1,y_1)$ and $h(x,y)=h(x_1,y_1)$, then this forces $g$ to be injective because we can draw a conclusion about $f(x,y)=f(x_1,y_1)$, but can't say anything about $h(x,y)=h(x_1,y_1)$, in the case that $h$ is not injective?  Is that why $f$ forces $g$ to be injective or is there another reason?

Comment: Exactly.  If every choice of $(x,y)$ gives you a different $x$-coordinate after applying $g$, then it doesn’t matter what happens in the $y$-coordinate: all the points will still be distinct.